# IQueryable<T> VS IEnumerable<T> how to see the differences in translated SQL commands?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Have been reading [questions & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704288/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable), [articles](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832189/List-vs-IEnumerable-vs-IQueryable-vs-ICollection-v), they all say:

By using `IEnumerable<T>`, it fetches all data from the database to your application's memory and then applies filters on top of it (this is unacceptable for my project); whereas `IQueryable<T>` is the saviour: it does the filtering in the database and then returns only the filtered data into memory.

In my ASP.NET Core with Kestrel project, I can see how the lambda expression or LINQ is translated into SQL commands (from the Kestrel console) and I have tried in my code to use both of them, but the translated SQL query looks the same:

[image]

Can anyone enlighten me how to see the differences please?

**Update**

Here is the code:

```
public IQueryable<Apartment> GetApartmentsByPostcode(string postcode, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
{
    return _dataContext.Apartment
                .Include(a => a.ApartmentDetails)
                .Where(a => string.Compare(a.PostCode, postcode, true) == 0 && a.Enabled == true)
                ?.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * countPerPage)
                ?.Take(30);
}
```

I switched between `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` (`.AsEnumerable()` at the end of the `Take(30)`)

I know `Take()`, `Skip`, `Where` etc. will return `IQueryable`, but there is no way to make them to return `IEnumerable` from the root.

So may I conclude it does not matter to use `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` as return type?

Comment: Edit your question and provide the code you used.

Comment: hi @MichaelLiu please see my update, thanks

Comment: Try putting .AsEnumerable() between .Include(…) and .Where(…).

Comment: hi @MichaelLiu I see your point. Normally, nobody will do that, it will be always that we do AsEnumerable() after Where or Take, OrderBy clause. So I guess it's safe to use IEnumerable as the return type as the Lambda expression will return IQueryable.

Comment: still trying to completely understand what you are trying to achieve. However, doesn't seem like `AsEnumerable` will do you any good. The operative word being **As**, it is only meant to encapsulate your output to IEnumerable and will have no logical difference

Comment: Difference between what exactly? "By using IEnumberable, it brings all data from DB to your application memory ..." have you tried this part yourself (if yes, can you share the code?) or have you just read it from the articles?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], including how `GetApartmentsByPostcode` is called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning IEnumerable<T> vs. IQueryable<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876616/returning-ienumerablet-vs-iqueryablet)

Comment: I wouldn't entirely call it a duplicate of that question. Based on the first para, I see the confusion in understanding when the queries execute too.